# Can you solve for x for the equation $25+2^{\log_{10} x}=x$?

Tags: logarithms

> Solve for $x$ : $$25+2^{\log_{10} x}=x$$

My work

Well, I could not figure out an algebraic solution to this problem.
$$25+2^{\log_{10} x}=x \implies 5^2+x^{\log_{10} 2}=x$$
$$\implies x^{\log_{10}2}-x-25=0$$
which does not seem to be solved further.

I have solved this by using the graphical method by plotting both sides of this equation. And the answer comes near to  $27.7$. I have also verified it by using the desmos graph calculator according to which the answer is $27.718$.

How can I solve this question by the algebraic method?

Comment: What is the base of your logarithm?  If it is $e$, [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25%2B2%5E%28log%28x%29%29%3Dx) gets 37.2824

Comment: These types of expressions generally don't have a "nice" algebraic solution. When both an exponential and a polynomial (such as $x$, $x^2$ and so on) appears in an equation, you usually don't have a chance to solve it algebraically.

Comment: the base is $10$.                                                                                                             $37.2$ comes when you take the base $e$

Comment: $$2^{\log_yx}=2^{\frac{\log_2x}{\log_2y}}=\sqrt[\log_2y]{2^{\log_2x}}=\sqrt[\log_2y]{x}$$ Note that the lack of a rational exponent for $x$ means that you are limited to numerical methods for solutions.

Comment: May be this manipulation help:

$10^{log_{10} x}-2^{log_{10} x}=25$

$2^{log_{10} x}\big(5^{log_{10} x }-1\big)=25$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solve for x :  \begin{align} 25+2^{\log_{10} x}=x \tag{1}\label{1} \end{align}

---

Note that \eqref{1} is equivalent to

\begin{align} 
x^{\log_{10}2}-x+25&=0
\tag{2}\label{2}
\\
\text{or }\quad
x^a-x+b&=0
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}
with non-rational $a$.
It is known that such equations
don't have an algebraic solution and
can be solved only by means of numerical methods.

For example, we can use [Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method)
to iteratively find the approximation of the root as

\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=F(x_n)
,\\
F(x)&=x-\frac{2\,f(x)\,f'(x)}{2f'(x)^2-f(x)\,f''(x)}
,\\
f(x)&=x^{\log_{10}(2)}-x+25
,\\
f'(x)&=\log_{10}(2)\cdot x^{\log_{10}(2)-1}-1
,\\
f''(x)&=\log_{10}(2)\log_{10}(\tfrac15)\cdot x^{\log_{10}(2)-2}
.
\end{align}

For example, starting with $x_0=1$, we get

\begin{align}
x_1&=6.60306336935\\
x_2&=26.5079884286\\
x_3&=27.7184046785\\
x_4&=27.7184201926\\
x_5&=27.7184201926\\
\end{align}

---

**Edit**

The rate of convergence to the root is cubic,
compare for example
to the [Newton's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3921796/122782):
starting with the same $x_0$, the Halley's approximations would be

\begin{align}
x_0&=\color{blue}{ 27}.386363636363636363636 \\ 
x_1&=\color{blue}{ 27.7184}19892956254689994 \\ 
x_2&=\color{blue}{ 27.718420192574854316455}
\end{align}

Corresponding `python` code:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 23

lg2 = decimal.Decimal(2).log10()

def f(x):
  return 25+x**lg2-x

def df(x):
  return lg2*x**(lg2-1)-1

def ddf(x):
  return lg2*(lg2-1)*x**(lg2-2)

def F(x):
  fx=f(x)
  dfx=df(x)
  ddfx=ddf(x)
  return x-2*fx*dfx/(2*dfx**2-fx*ddfx)

x=decimal.getcontext().divide(1205,44); print(x)
x=F(x); print(x)
x=F(x); print(x)
x=F(x); print(x)

# 27.386363636363636363636
# 27.718419892956254689994
# 27.718420192574854316455
# 27.718420192574854316455
```

Comment: Normally, starting with $x_0=\frac{1205}{44}$, the first iterate of Halley mathod should be $27.7184198929563$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Thanks, that must be a copy/paste typo, fixed.

Comment: *You know what ? I am happy !* for seeing used the real Halley formulation. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Thanks, you're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=25+2^{\log_{10}( x)}-x$$and use inspection. You have $f(10)=17$ and $f(100)=-71$. Compute the equation of the straight line going through the two points. It is
$$y=\frac{241}{9}-\frac{44 x}{45} \implies x_0=\frac{1205}{44}\approx 27.3864$$ and
$$f\left(\frac{1205}{44}\right)\approx 0.322212$$ We are so close to the solution that any iterative method would converge very fast. Below are some numbers with a ridiculous number of figures starting with $x_0=\frac{1205}{44}$ and using Newton method

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & \color{red}{27.}386363636363636364 \\
 1 & \color{red}{27.7184}63076353301887 \\
 2 & \color{red}{27.71842019257}5559688 \\
 3 & \color{red}{27.718420192574854316}
\end{array}
\right)$$